# Accessing com.google.mms.pdu and com.android.mms

Tags: android, mms

So I am trying to access various class files in these package names, I have downloaded the following library 
http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/
If you look on the page and browse through the various files you will clearly see com.google.mms.pdu and the many classes inside.  However, after downloading the jar file and adding it to my project there is no com.google and it is driving me insane, I have downloaded all the older packages on this page and have found that older releases like 1.5_r5 do have this package inside them but the newer releases don't! Has anyone had any problem with this?

I am trying to follow this tutorial
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2222703
with the older library I can add most of the required packages but I am still missing com.android.mms.transaction.HttpUtils.java none of these libraries have any package beginning with com.android.mms

*UPDATE*
I have found that com.android.mms.transaction is in the 4.4.2 package even though the webpage does not list it.  However when I try to use HttpUtils.httpConection intellisense does not recognize the method even though the library shows it.

The Ideal solution would be to find a library that has the proper packages I am looking for without giving me these messed up errors

Comment: Don't you mean com.google.android.mms, and not com.android.mms?